# for the list in python, how can I realize following function?

Tags: python, list

if I have

```
[[[A1]],[[A2]],...]
```

and

```
[[[B1]],[[B2]],...],
```

and after the operation expecting the result as

```
[[[A1,B1]],[[A2,B2]],...]
```

I tried to use numpy to transform it into narray, but the result is not good

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us your attempt using numpy (and that's `ndarray` in full or `array` in short, not `narray`.) This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. If there was any error message, show the full traceback. And do you want an answer not using numpy?

Comment: We do not code for you, we help you fix _your code_. If you have a specific problem, consider studying [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) , provide code respecting [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to use `numpy` to do this. You can do it with list comprehension and the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
listA = [[['A1']],[['A2']],[['A3']]]
listB = [[['B1']],[['B2']],[['B3']]]

output = [[elemA[0] + elemB[0]] for elemA, elemB in zip(listA,listB)]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[[['A1', 'B1']], [['A2', 'B2']], [['A3', 'B3']]]
```

or you can use the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map) function along with `zip`:

```
output = list(map(lambda elem: elem[0] + elem[1], zip(listA,listB)))
```

Comment: great! it totally solves my question! but just a small details:output += [[elemA[0] + elemB[0]] for elemA, elemB in zip(listA,listB)]

Comment: You need to initialize `output` first: `output = []` if you want to use the `+=` operator. Glad to help anyway. Feel free to upvote or accept it as answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
l1 = [[['A1']], [['A2']], [['A3']]]
l2 = [[['B1']], [['B2']], [['B3']]]

new = [[sum(i+j, [])] for i, j in zip(l1, l2)]
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native python functions as:

```
def generate_list(letter='A', count=10):
    result = []
    for i in range(count):
        item = "{}{}".format(letter, i)
        result.append([[item]])
    return result


first_list = generate_list()
second_list = generate_list(letter='B')

result = []
for first, second in zip(first_list, second_list):
    result.append([[first[0][0], second[0][0]]])
```

or

```
def generate_list(letter='A', count=10):
    result = []
    for i in range(count):
        item = "{}{}".format(letter, i)
        result.append([[item]])
    return result


first_list = generate_list()
second_list = generate_list(letter='B')

result = list(map(lambda first, second:
                  [[first[0][0], second[0][0]]],
                  first_list, second_list))
```